# Testing if an array or linked list is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list

I am doing a problem on Leetcode to write a function which checks to see if a supplied array is a palindrome. They seem to expect the solution to involve creating a linked list from the array and then using the linked list to check if its contents are a palindrome.

Am I right in assuming that the reason for using a linked list (other than to test your programming skills) is that it enables a more efficient (ie takes less processing power) solution than working solely with arrays?

What I find counter intuitive about that is the fact that the function takes an array as its argument so, the data is already in an array. My thinking is that it must take as much processing power to get the array into a linked list as it would take to just go through the elements in the array from each end checking each pair to see if they are equal.

In order to make the linked list you would have to access all the array elements. The only thing I can think is that accessing elements from the end of array might be more 'expensive' than from the front.

I have put my code for solving the problem with an array below:

```js
function isPalindrome(array){
    const numberOfTests = Math.floor(array.length/2);
    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++){
        let j = array.length - 1 - i;
        if(array[i] !== array[j]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
console.log(isPalindrome([1,1,1,2]))
```

I guess my question is why are they suggesting using linked lists to solve this problem other than to test programming skills? Is there something about my function which is less efficient than using a linked list to accomplish the same task?

**Edit:**

The code editor for the question is pre-populated with:

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    
};
```

Also from the question:

> The number of nodes in the list is in the range [1, 105].
> 0 <= Node.val <= 9

> Follow up: Could you do it in O(n) time and O(1) space?

I am not exactly sure what this all means but I interpreted it as suggesting there are performance issues involve with the algorithm and that using linked lists would be a good way to address them.

The problem is at: https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/

Comment: *"They seem to expect the solution to involve creating a linked list"*: please quote the code challenge (and add a link) so we can assess for ourselves what they expect. Without that we cannot really answer your question. It might well be that you misunderstand the code challenge.

Comment: @trincot I have edited with the question and also put a link to the problem.

Comment: One of LeetCode's goals is to help you learn common algorithms, programming patterns, and data structures (language agnostic) in a puzzle-oriented way. There's nothing wrong with your approach, except that the input is not an array, so it is not valid for the problem constraints. The main purpose of this problem is for you to understand what a [singly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) data structure is and to begin to learn about [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks! I have got a clearer idea of that from the responses to my question. The thing I am unclear about now is how the same thing, for example `[1,2,2,1]`, can sometimes represent an array and other times a linked list. It would be great to get an angle on that.

Comment: @user3425506 I see the confusion. I'll write up an answer to help you visualize the misunderstanding.

Comment: @jsejcksn I would appreciate that! trincot has made a pretty good job of it in his comments and answer but another take on it would definitely help.

Comment: @user3425506 I posted it for you. Additionally: solving the problems in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead of JavaScript will give you an even better understanding of the data structures involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code challenge is saying that you are *"given the head of a singly linked list"*. So it is *not* an array. The misunderstanding may come from the way that LeetCode *represents* a linked list: they use an array notation for it. But be assured that your function will be called with a linked list, not an array.

> Am I right in assuming that the reason for using a linked list (other than to test your programming skills) is that it enables a more efficient (ie takes less processing power) solution than working solely with arrays?

No, it is only for testing programming skills.

> What I find counter intuitive about that is the fact that the function takes an array as its argument

This is where you got the code challenge wrong. Look at the description (*"Given the head of a singly linked list"*), and look at the template code you get to start from (the parameter is named `head`, not `array`).

> Is there something about my function which is less efficient than using a linked list to accomplish the same task?

Your function will not work. The argument does not have a `length` property since it is not an array. The argument is an instance of `ListNode` or `null`.

In your code you included a call of your function. But that is not how LeetCode will call your function. It will not be called like:

```
isPalindrome([1, 2, 2, 1])
```

But like:

```
isPalindrome(new ListNode(1, 
             new ListNode(2, 
             new ListNode(2, 
             new ListNode(1)))))
```

Comment: thanks for clearing up the performance issue and identifying my incorrect assumption that the argument is an array.  I am confused how [1,2,2,1] can be anything other than an array. Can it behave as an array or a linked list depending what is done to it? Also, if I think of [1,2,2,1] as a linked list, surely it is not the head of a linked list which I thought was a single node. I would really appreciate some more illumination if possible.

Comment: [1,2,2,1] is just a *representation* for *displaying* the input in some readable format. It is not literally what you get as argument -- it would not even make sense in other programming languages where array literals are not written like that, but with braces, or still something else. So just forget the idea that this is an array. It is just a representation of what the linked list has as data. The Leet Code framework will pass a linked list. The function is **not** called like `isPalindrome([1, 2, 2, 1])`, but `isPalindrome(new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, new ListNode(2, new ListNode(1)))))`

Comment: that definitely makes some sense. In some ways the 'Leet Code framework' is slightly obscuring what is going on because I have to put something like [1,2,2,1] into the Testcase but it presumably converts that to a linked list to call the function. If I was developing the function on my own without LeetCode I would call the function as you suggested or with a variable that pointed to linked list.

Comment: The history behind this, is that code challenges take input from standard input, and produce output to standard output. But then code challenge sites started to provide boilerplate code that did the work of reading the input and writing the output, so that your function could concentrate on the essence. At LeetCode the input format is something that looks like JSON, no matter what the eventual data structure should be like. In this case LeetCode converts that **text** (not array) `[1,2,2,1]` into a linked list for you, and only then calls your function.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you have described it, no matter if we analyse this issue via big-O time complexity or empirical performance, there is *no real reason* to convert it to a linked list first. It will definitely slow your program down.

This is relatively easy to comprehend: in order to create the linked list, you have to access the whole array. How is this slower than accessing the array elements to determine if it is a palindrome? In terms of array access operations, we are accessing each of the array elements at most once  (ideally), in each case. However, with the linked list approach we also have to spend time to create the linked list and then determine if *that* is a palindrome.

It's like if you're doing a math question, instead of doing it on the piece of paper it was given on, copying it to a piece of parchment first and doing it there. You aren't saving time.

Albeit, the time complexity for both should be `O(N)` worst-case, and their runtimes should not differ drastically as the difference is only a small constant.

Converting to a linked list is probably only for demonstrative reasons, **not** performance reasons.

Comment: although I do not understand big-O etc, what you are saying does agree with what I was thinking. I was clearly wrong to think there was an assumption that linked lists were more efficient than arrays for solving this task.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by reiterating my comment for some context:

One of LeetCode's goals is to help you learn common algorithms, programming patterns, and data structures (language agnostic) in a puzzle-oriented way. There's nothing wrong with your approach, except that the input is not an array, so it is not valid for the problem constraints. The main purpose of this problem is for you to understand what a [singly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) data structure is and to begin to learn about [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Based on the details of your question and your follow-up comments, it sounds like you're having trouble with the first part: understanding the structure of a singly-linked list. This is understandable if your experience is in JavaScript: a singly-linked list is not a common data structure in comparison to arrays.

Included in the description details of [the problem that you linked to](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/), is the following:

> **Example 1:**
>
> [image: pal1linked-list]
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,2,1]
> Output: true
> ```

The way that the `head` input argument is shown in the text uses the same syntax as an array of numbers in JavaScript. This is only an [abstract](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstract) (theoretical way of looking at things) representation of a linked list. It **does NOT** mean literally:

```
const head = [1, 2, 2, 1];
```

A linked list is a nested structure of nodes, each having a value and (maybe) a child node. The `head` input example *actually* looks like this JavaScript data structure:

```
const head = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 2,
      next: {
        val: 1,
        next: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This might seem new/confusing to you (and that's ok). This data structure is much more common in some other languages. There will be other problems on LeetCode that will be more familiar to you (and less familiar to programmers who work in those languages): it's part of the challenge and enjoyment of learning.

If the site content maintainers ever consider updating the problem details for each code puzzle, it might be a good idea to provide custom description information based on which language is selected, so that this kind of confusion happens less often.

Comment: that is a very nice explanation! One thing I am wondering is whether using 'head' as the name for the argument to the function makes sense. Would 'linkedList' be a more appropriate name for it? I am not trying to be pedantic but am thinking maybe there is something else which I am failing to understand.